# Dynamically set values to variables in React/React Native .map function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to dynamically set the value to variables in ***.map*** function but it appears to syntax errors. Please help me out.

I used to use {} to wrap the JavaScript code in html but this time it didn't work as expected.

Additionally I also wondering that is it possible to access variables stored in the local state object within .map function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
    class SearchListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, shortDescription, time, locationDescription, peopleGroup } = this.props.item;
    const indexX = -28;
    const indexZ = 1.1;
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={{ width: '90%' }}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ width: '10%' }}>
            <Icon
              name='star-outline'
              type='material-community'
              color='#666666' />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 5, color: '#666666' }}>{shortDescription}</Text>
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>{time}</Text>
          <Text style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>{locationDescription}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20  }}>
          {const i = 0}
          peopleGroup.map((people) => (
            <Avatar
              width={30}
              position='absolute'
              containerStyle={{ transform: [{translate: [-28 + (28 * i), 0, 20]}] }}
              small
              rounded
              source={{uri: "http://www.5seestar.com/jiaoxuewen/images/1701/dengchao.jpg"}}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              />          ));

        </View>

      </View>

    );
  }
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    padding: 30,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 5
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18
  }
};

export default SearchListItem;
```

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-assign-value-to-a-variable-inside-a-react-js-map-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want to do is to use the index of the mapped value, so you can use this i guess :

```
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20  }}>
          {
            peopleGroup.map((people,i) => (
              <Avatar
                 width={30}
                 position='absolute'
                 containerStyle={{ transform: [{translate: [-28 + (28 * i), 0, 20]}] }}
                 small
                 rounded
                 source={{uri:"http://www.5seestar.com/jiaoxuewen/images/1701/dengchao.jpg"}}
      activeOpacity={0.7}
              />
           ));
          }
   </View>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I have add i as params in the function but program end up with ReferenceError. Can't find variable i

Comment: You need to wrap your peopleGroup.map() inside of a `{}`

Comment: I have warped .map function with {} like Dan said. All working properly now. Thanks for help from you guys.